# Enforce tagging for AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, amazon-iam

I understand that we can enforce tagging on resources on AWS by introducing IAM policies, for example for EC2,

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyCreateInstanceWithoutApplicationIDtag",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:RequestTag/ApplicationID": "*"
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to enforce the same policies to other resources such as route table, VPC attachment and so on.

I found out that below does not work:

```
 {
        "Sid": "DenyCreateRouteTableWithoutApplicationIDtag",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "ec2:CreateRouteTable",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:routetable/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:RequestTag/ApplicationID": "*"
            }
        }
    }
```

Will anyone know why this is the case?  Is there a better way to enforce tagging on all taggable resources, instead of writing IAM policy per resource type?

Comment: I removed the answer for now. I want to try this: "To force users to specify tags when they create a resource, you must use the aws:RequestTag condition key or the aws:TagKeys condition key with the ForAnyValue modifier on the resource-creating action. The ec2:CreateTags action is not evaluated if a user does not specify tags for the resource-creating action. " from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/supported-iam-actions-tagging.html).

Comment: thanks.  I tried aws:RequestTag condition above but it didnt seem to work for Route table, but EC2 it works - users cannot provision EC2, unless the tag ApplicationID is added and has a value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ec2:CreateRoutetable` action targets VPC resources, not Route Table resources (which is what you currently have in your `Resource` entry).

Try changing your `Resource` block to include `arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*` (i.e. all VPCs in all regions).

You can see the detail (supported resources and conditions, etc) in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-vpc).

Comment: Hi @Rowanu, thank you for your answer, I try changing the resource block to "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*" , and it seem now even if i have a tag for ApplicationID in route table, it is also blocked.

Comment: Ah, does it have other tags being created at the same time? Maybe that's hitting the deny.

Comment: No other tags being created.  Just the ApplicationID tag was added.